# Изменение размера изображения относительно другого с сохранением пропорций

Tags: php, математика, графика, геометрия

Есть два изображения:
`photo.png` (500x500px) - изображение на которое нужно наложить водяной знак(watermark)
`watermark.png` (240x80px) - водяной знак

Я изменяю размер `watermark.png` таким образом, чтобы он занимал не больше 30% площади по ширине от `photo.png`, и не больше 30% по высоте.
Проценты от площади я знаю как получить, делаю примерно так:

```
$watermarkWidth = $photoWidth / 100 * 30; // 30% от photo.png
$watermarkHeight = $photoHeight / 100 * 30; // 30% от photo.png
```

Но я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы после ресайза `watermark.png` не сплющивался, и слишком сильно не растягивался, т.е. мне нужны такие размеры `$watermarkWidth` и `$watermarkHeight` при которых `watermark.png` будет пропорционален исходному размеру, и при этом новый размер должен быть максимально близок к 30% от размера `photo.png`

Comment: как делается ресайз?

Comment: @Эникейщик рейсайз выполняется средствами библиотеки `Imagine\Image`, и методом `resize`  (не думаю, что это важно)

Comment: Перечитал вопрос. В чем проблема - в сохранении пропорций или в том, чтобы итоговый размер был максимально близок к 30% площади?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как я понял поставленную задачу: вам требуется добавить ватермарку на
>   исходное изображение, при этом изменяя её размер относительно
>   оригинала, не теряя её пропорциональность.

---

### Ошибка (сразу к сути)

Ваша ошибка была в том, что вы пытались растянуть изображение своей ватермарки сразу по 2 осям *(x и y)*. Как я понял исходные изображения будут разного размера, и вероятность того что 30% одновременно и от ширины и от высоты дадут вам пропорциональную ватермарку - крайне мала.

---

### Решение

Не стоит гнаться за двумя зайцами и строить свой код относительно 2 осей. Лучше взять всего одну и изменить размер ватермарки операясь на неё, после чего высчитать коэффициент этого изменения и операясь уже на него, работать с противоположной осью.

---

## Замечание

В примерах ниже, будет использованы функции библиотеки GD.
Чтобы они работали, она должна присутствовать в вашем php.
О GD можно узнать тут: http://php.net/manual/ru/image.setup.php

---

## Пример

Получим нужное нам изображение и основу для ватермарки.

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('1.jpg'); //Основное изображение
$wm_source = imagecreatefrompng('2.png'); //Изображение ватермарки
```

Узнаем, ширину и высоту интересующих нас изображений.

```
$im_width = imagesx($im); //Ширина изображения
$im_height = imagesy($im); //Высота изображения
$wm_source_width = imagesx($wm_source); //Ширина основы ватермарки
$wm_source_height = imagesy($wm_source); //Высота основы ватермарки
```

А теперь самое интересное. Вычислим новую ширину для нашей ватермарки, относительно ширины исходного изображения. Это будет ровно 30 % от ширины исходного изображения.

```
$wm_width = ($im_width / 100) * 30; //Ширина резайзнутой ватермарки (30% от изображения)
```

После чего, вычислим коэффициент изменения ширины нашей ватермарки, поделив её размер *(полученный чуть выше)* на размер её основы.

```
$co = $wm_width / $wm_source_width; //Коэффициент изменения
```

И уже с помощью этого коэффициента, рассчитаем высоту нашей ватермарки.

```
$wm_height = $wm_source_height * $co; //Высота ватермирки
```

> Таким образом, мы смогли не потерять пропорциональность ватермарки и уложится в ограничение в 30% от изображения. Если говорить по простому: мы просто взяли и изменили высоту ватермарки ровно на столько же на столько изменили и её ширину, там самым не потеряв пропорциональность.

> Ведь если умножить 2 числа на одно и тоже их отношение не поменяется,
>   а это и есть пропорциональность.

Теперь укажем где, будет находится наша ватермарка, в данном случае взят левый нижний угол изначального изображения. *(никто вам не мешает выбрать другой)*

```
$wm_x = $im_width - $wm_width; //Позиция x ватермарки
$wm_y = $im_height - $wm_height; //Позиция y ватермарки
```

Создадим само изображение для нашей ватермарки. *Стоит заметить что $wm_source - это шаблон, основа, оригинальное изображение нашей ватермарки, в то время как $wm - будет уже тем, что мы добавим в нужное нам изображение*

```
$wm = imagecreatetruecolor($wm_width,$wm_height); //Создаём новую ватермарку
```

Изменяем размер ватермарки, с параметрами которые мы определили ранее.

```
imagecopyresampled($wm,$wm_source,0,0,0,0,$wm_width,$wm_height,$wm_source_width,$wm_source_height); //Изменяем размер ватермарки
```

Вставляем ватермарку на нужное нам изображение.

```
imagecopy($im,$wm,$wm_x,$wm_y,0,0,$wm_width,$wm_height); //Вставляем ватермарку
```

---

## Вывод

Вот и всё, я надеюсь я помог в решении вашей проблемы. Ниже я приложу полный код программы, чтобы вы могли без проблем его запустить. Это мой первый ответ на StackOverflow, и я мог где то ошибиться или чего-то не учесть, если это действительно так, то укажите на мои ошибки пожалуйста.

---

## Полный код программы

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('1.jpg'); //Основное изображение
$wm_source = imagecreatefrompng('2.png'); //Изображение ватермарки

$im_width = imagesx($im); //Ширина изображения
$im_height = imagesy($im); //Высота измениния

$wm_source_width = imagesx($wm_source); //Ширина основы ватермарки
$wm_source_height = imagesy($wm_source); //Высота основы ватермарки

$wm_width = ($im_width / 100) * 30; //Ширина резайзнутой ватермарки (30% от изображения)
$co = $wm_width / $wm_source_width; //Коофицент изменения
$wm_height = $wm_source_height * $co; //Высота ватермирки

$wm_x = $im_width - $wm_width; //Позиция x ватермарки
$wm_y = $im_height - $wm_height; //Позиция y ватермарки

$wm = imagecreatetruecolor($wm_width,$wm_height); //Создаём новую ватермарку
imagecopyresampled($wm,$wm_source,0,0,0,0,$wm_width,$wm_height,$wm_source_width,$wm_source_height); //Изменяем размер ватермарки

imagecopy($im,$wm,$wm_x,$wm_y,0,0,$wm_width,$wm_height); //Вставляем ватермарку

imagepng($im); //Выводим результат
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну варианта два:
Ресайз с искажением

```
$watermarkWidth = $photoWidth / 100 * 30; // 30% от photo.png
$watermarkHeight = $photoHeight / 100 * 30; // 30% от photo.png
```

Ресайз по минимальному параметру

```
$i = $watermarkWidth/$watermarkHeight; // соотношение сторон вотермарки

if($photoWidth<$photoHeight){
  $watermarkWidth = $photoWidth / 100 * 30; // 30% от photo.
  $watermarkHeight = $watermarkWidth/$i; 
}else{
  $watermarkHeight = $photoHeight / 100 * 30; // 30% от photo.
  $watermarkWidth = $watermarkHeight*$i; 
}
```

В первом случае вотермарка будет искажаться в зависимость от размера изображения, а во втором она будет занимать 30% от ширины либо высоты